# How to link functions to a menu in C

Tags: c, function, menu

My program is about giving a sentence as an input and then from a menu choosing to: 1) count the words of the sentence, 2)Title casing the senctence, 3) exit the program. I have created individually both functions but i am having trouble connecting each function to the corresponding choice in the menu and making it work.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX 100

int Word_count(char *);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int choice;
    char str[999];
    printf("Enter a sentence: "); gets(str);

    do
    {
        printf("\n\n-----Menu-----\n\n");
        printf("1. How many words does the scentence contain?\n");
        printf("2. Title the scentence.\n");
        printf("3. Exit\n");
        scanf("%d",&choice);

        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1: Word_count(str);
                break;
            case 2: Title_case();
                break;
            case 3: printf("Exiting program!\n");
                exit(0);
                break;
            default: printf("Invalid choice!\n");
                break;
        }

    } while (choice != 3);

}


void Title_case(void)
{
    char str[MAX]={0};  
    int i;

    printf("Enter a string: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]s",str); 

    for(i=0; str[i]!='\0'; i++)
    {
        if(i==0)
        {
            if((str[i]>='a' && str[i]<='z'))
                str[i]=str[i]-32; 
            continue; 
        }
        if(str[i]==' ')
        {
            ++i;

            if(str[i]>='a' && str[i]<='z')
            {
                str[i]=str[i]-32; 
                continue; 
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(str[i]>='A' && str[i]<='Z')
                str[i]=str[i]+32; 
        }
    }

    printf("Title Cased string is: %s\n",str);

    return ;
}

int Word_count(char *str){
    int i = 0, len, count= 0;
    len = strlen(str);

    if(str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'z')
    {
       count ++;
    }

    for (i = 1; i<len; i++) 
    {
        if((str[i]==' ' || str[i]=='\t' || str[i]=='\n')&& str[i+1] >= 'A' && str[i+1] <= 'z')
        {
        count++;
        }
    }
printf("there are %d words", Word_count(str));
return count;

}
```

Comment: <O/T> use [fgets](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) instead of `gets`, which is a huge security vulnerability

Comment: The `printf` at the end of `Word_count` calls `Word_count` recursively, which is not what you want. Just `printf("there are %d words\n", count)` is probably what you meant to do.

Comment: Why do you ask for a string in function `Title_case` again? The local `str`-array hides the one from the main function. Why don't you pass it simply to the function like you did it in `Word_count`?
You also may want to pass `str` as `const` to show that it is read-only.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I used your suggestions and it works perfectly fine!

Answer (score 2):

in `Word_count` function you're calling the function itself again (mistakenly for sure). I'm guessing you put it there for debugging purposes.

Change it to: `printf("there are %d words", count);`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I used your suggestions and it works perfectly fine!